# How to properly map shared element transition from RecyclerView to ViewPager dynamically?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

I have an activity that hosts both fragments called **`SourceFragment`** and **`DestinationFragment`**. The `SourceFragment` contains a `RecyclerView` and the `DestinationFragment` contains a `ViewPager`. I've been using the fragment manager to swap back and forth between the Source and Destination fragment.

Issue:

The return transition works normally as long as I don't swipe to a different view on the ViewPager. To resolve this I overrode the `onMapSharedElements` in the `DestinationFragment` and the `SourceFragment` to make sure the views match each other when the view pager is swiped. 
For some reason swiping and returning to the SourceFragment doesn't work and no transition animation happens. I even debugged the `onMapSharedElements` functions to make sure that the views mapped correctly.

[This is what I'm trying to implement.](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-SNCtXE5hWnA/WodR6VvS1CI/AAAAAAAAFGA/S4875u4sF8E2cALkutydZ-5F_1qMTaIgwCLcBGAs/s1600/app-with-transitions.gif)

[My implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoITxJrSuyU)

I've provided the code below for the fragments in question but here is the [repo](https://github.com/arsonistAnt/SharedElementTest) to my implementation. Been itching my head for a week now trying to figure this out hopefully I can get some insight as to why this is happening.

SourceFragment:

```
class SourceFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel
private lateinit var itemRecyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var adapter: SourceAdapter
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setExitSharedElementCallback(object : SharedElementCallback() {
        override fun onMapSharedElements(names: MutableList<String>?, sharedElements: MutableMap<String, View>?) {
            val view = itemRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(sharedViewModel.currentPos)
                ?.itemView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.source_text)
            val item = sharedViewModel.itemList[sharedViewModel.currentPos]
            if (view == null) return
            names?.clear()
            sharedElements?.clear()
            names?.add(item)
            sharedElements?.put(item, view)
        }
    })

    sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)

    adapter = SourceAdapter(object : onClickItem {
        override fun onClick(position: Int, view: View) {
            // Save the position of the item that was clicked.
            sharedViewModel.currentPos = position

            // Setup shared element transition
            val transitionName = ViewCompat.getTransitionName(view) ?: ""

            // Start fragment transaction along with shared element transition.
            fragmentManager?.apply {
                beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .addSharedElement(view, transitionName)
                    .replace(
                        R.id.fragment_container,
                        DestinationFragment(),
                        DestinationFragment::class.java.simpleName
                    )
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit()
            }
        }
    })

    val list = sharedViewModel.itemList
    adapter.submitList(list)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.source_layout, container, false)
    postponeEnterTransition()
    return view
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // Setup recycler view here
    itemRecyclerView = item_recycler_view
    itemRecyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2)
    itemRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

    // Start enter transition on pre draw.
    itemRecyclerView.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
        override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
            itemRecyclerView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
            startPostponedEnterTransition()
            return true
        }
    })

    // Scroll to the position of the item that was selected in the Destination Fragment.
    itemRecyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener { p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8 ->
        val layoutMan = itemRecyclerView.layoutManager
        val viewAtPos = layoutMan?.findViewByPosition(sharedViewModel.currentPos)
        if (viewAtPos == null ||
            layoutMan.isViewPartiallyVisible(viewAtPos, false, true)
        ) {
            itemRecyclerView.post {
                layoutMan?.scrollToPosition(sharedViewModel.currentPos)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DestinationFragment

```
class DestinationFragment : Fragment(), MainActivityListener {
lateinit var sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel
lateinit var destPager : ViewPager
lateinit var itemAdapter : ItemPagerAdapter
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    postponeEnterTransition()
    setEnterSharedElementCallback(object : androidx.core.app.SharedElementCallback(){
        override fun onMapSharedElements(names: MutableList<String>?, sharedElements: MutableMap<String, View>?) {
            val item = sharedViewModel.itemList[destPager.currentItem]
            val itemView = (itemAdapter.instantiateItem(destPager, destPager.currentItem) as Fragment).view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_fragment_textview) as View
            names?.clear()
            names?.add(item)
            sharedElements?.clear()
            sharedElements?.put(item, itemView)
        }
    })

    sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(requireContext()).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.move)
    sharedViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get( SharedViewModel::class.java)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.destination_layout, container ,false)
}

override fun onBackPressed(): Boolean {
    sharedViewModel.currentPos = destPager.currentItem
    return false
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    destPager = destination_pager
    itemAdapter = ItemPagerAdapter(sharedViewModel.itemList, childFragmentManager)
    destination_pager.adapter = itemAdapter
    destination_pager.currentItem = sharedViewModel.currentPos
}
```

Comment: When I was doing a gallery with that behavior I had transparent activity instead of replacing the fragments. Maybe it was a little hack, but that way `recyclerView` below was not destroyed and I could scroll it alongside pager.

Comment: Hmm I guess I'll go this route if I can't figure out whats wrong with my implementation.